# wkhtmltopdf: Custom TOC style with --toc-header-text attribute

Tags: pdf, xslt, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, tableofcontents

I'm using the [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) library to generate PDF files with options

```
--toc-header-text TEXT --xsl-style-sheet config/wkhtmltopdf_toc.xsl
```

but the `--toc-header-text` value is not inserted to the generated table of contents.

Is there a way to insert the value of `--toc-header-text` variable to the custom TOC stylesheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it's not an answer, but it is working workaround

I create a temp file with toc stylesheet for each generated pdf, replace title text with my dynamic content and pass this file to wkhtmltopdf

in Ruby it can be something like:

```
toc_file = Tempfile.new
toc_content = File.
  read('config/wkhtmltopdf_toc.xsl').
  gsub(':index_title', title)
toc_file.write(toc_content)
toc_file.rewind
```

pass the file path to wkhtmltopdf -- `toc_file.path`

destroy the file after pdf is generated:

```
toc_file.close
toc_file.unlink
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XSLT magic to define a variable based on the name of the first outline item (which is the TOC itself).

I did this:

```
<xsl:variable name="tocTitle" select="//outline:outline/outline:item[1]/@title" />
<xsl:template match="outline:outline">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title><xsl:value-of select="$tocTitle" /></title>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="$tocTitle" /></h1>
        <ul><xsl:apply-templates select="outline:item/outline:item"/></ul>
    </body>
    </html>
...
```

This was painful trial and error (I am NOT an expert at this, happy for someone to correct me if I did this wrong). I messed around on https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html until it worked.